# I want to call a class function written in Swift from the AppDelegate (which is in Objective C). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift file "SomeController.swift" it is like this:

```
import Foundation

func performSomeStuff() {

println("Performing stuff")

}
```

Now in the app delegate, I am trying to do this: (note that the swift bridging header is imported)

```
[SomeController performSomeStuff]
```

But its not working.

I have also tried this:

```
import Foundation

class SomeController:NSObject {

  class func performSomeStuff() {

     println("Performing stuff")

  }

}
```

But it still fails.

What is the correct way?

Comment: make you func static

Comment: @RomanSimenok The only difference between static and class is that class methods can be overriden by a subclass, doesn't change anything here

Comment: What do you mean fails, does it compile, but you don't see `"Performing stuff"?  Does it fail early with an error message?  If so, what message? etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
@objc
```

before the class keyword in your swift code so it will be:

```
@objc class SomeStuff: NSObject {

}
```

Also add @obj in front of any function that you want to call.

Then in your app delegate make sure to use #import "projectName-Swift.h"

Comment: The @objc attribute is implicitly added to every `NSObject` so that won't change anything. The `#import "projectName-Swift.h"` is the thing OP has to do

Comment: ... and then, to finish the thought for the original poster, the `class func` declaration is correct, not the classless `func`.

Comment: I did add the swift bridging header file. But still didnt get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access "SomeController" class in objective-c, if not then you firstly need to add "${ProjectName}-Swift.h file and add Swift compilation support in Build settings as:

[image]

And for accessing methods from Swift to Objective-C, add 
import Foundation

```
class SomeStuff:NSObject {

  @objc class func performSomeStuff() {

     println("Performing stuff")

  }

}
```

before functions name.

> In some cases, you need finer grained control over how your Swift API is exposed to Objective-C. You can use the @objc attribute if your Swift class doesn’t inherit from an Objective-C class, or if you want to change the name of a symbol in your interface as it’s exposed to Objective-C code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: Yes I am. And I do have the swift bridging header imported

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I figured it out. First, here's the correct way. Its like some of you said:

In the swift file, I have it like this:

```
class MyController:NSObject{

  class func performTask {
    // Here my task is running.
  }
}
```

Then in the app delegate, I just import the swift header file. And do this:

```
[MyController performTask];
```

Now for the part I had wrong. It was an error on my part, but maybe it'll be useful to someone else out there.

When I first created the first swift file, I had placed it inside a folder within the my Source folder. But when I started having multiple swift files, I moved the bridging header outside that folder and into the main Source folder (just for organising).

The problem was, it did not give me a direct error to tell me what was the problem. I had to check the issue navigator to identify the problem.

Hope this helps someone out there.